# Hot to get rid of "ghost pixels"?

Tags: macos, display, imac

So I just noticed that some parts of the window I just closed are still being displayed but very lightly. I don't know the correct terminology for them but it looks very interesting. The only problem is, how do I get rid of them. They don't show up on screenshots but they overlay every window that is open. I'm using an iMac 2013 model with the latest version of Mac OS X. I already restarted the computer, installed new drivers etc. but nothing seems to work...

[image]

It's not very visible but it annoys me no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be image persistence. I have it on my iMac where the dock is, I can see it on the screen if I move the location of the dock. It will go away over time, and displaying an all-white image will help. Apple has [more information](https://discussions.apple.com/article/HT2807) on their support site.